# C++: call copy assignment in copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, variable-assignment

OK,I am reading "effective C++" and item 12 says please don't call copy assignment in copy constructor.But after I try to do this, it does work. So I want to ask why, I can't reuse the copy assignment code in copy constructor?

Comment: I think it's because probably more effective member initialization through taking direct copies of them in the initializer list.

Comment: I have a feeling this is well explained in item 12 of "Effective C++".

Comment: Hopefully all answer will be explaining more or less the same thing what Scott has explained there in _Item 12_

Comment: Near the end of the item 12, you have an explanation: "Performing an assignment on an object under construction would mean doing something to a not-yet-initialized object that makes sense only for an intialized object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you use copy-assignment operator in copy-constructor. Then you lose the ability to implement [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom for assignment operator:

```
struct A
{
   A (const A &a)
   {
     *this = a; // Assignment to a not yet constructed object is not well
   }

   A &operator=(A a) // Pass by value
   {
      // ...
   }
};

A a1, a2;
a1 = a2; // Infinite recursion!
```

It's not possible and infinite recursion will occur.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is useful. It will cause infinite recursion if the argument is passed by value and it's not well to assign to a not ye constructed object. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote up.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor creates a new object; an assignment operator modifies an existing object. You can't use an assignment operator to create a new object: it doesn't know how to do that, even if it seems to work in simple cases.